# How to distribute a gmail app script

Tags: gmail-addons

I have an app script that I would like to distribute in developer mode. It does not have an interactive UI. The script itself does a search and forwards messages based on specific parameters. It works flawlessly on a simple timed trigger. When I test it as a developer add-on, it does nothing in the test account. I assume the issue is with the json code.

```
{
  "timeZone": "**********",
   "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://mail.google.com/"


  ],
   "gmail": {
    "name": "Test",
     "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
     "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png"
   },
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Gmail",
      "serviceId": "gmail",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem @OrtenzioSticca? I don't think we can ask a Gmail Addon to use a simple time-driven trigger. Have you found a way to do it?